# HTTPS Client in python with SSL Authentication

Tags: python, ssl, https

I am using Python 2.x.  I need to develop a python client that will communicate via HTTPS with authentication using certificates and keys.  I have searched the internet but this newbie is very confused.  Is it done with only SSL like [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027865/python-client-authentication-using-ssl-and-socket) or with [httplib](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577548-https-httplib-client-connection-with-certificate-v/)?

Does anyone have a basic client example?

This is my idea of what the code would look like:

```
import ssl, socket

key = mykeyfile
cert = mycertfile
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,keyfile=key,certfile=cert,server_side=False)
ssl_sock.connect(("www.xxx.xxx", 443))
# This is where I call a method the server has exposed
ssl_sock.callServerMethod(arg1,arg2)
```

Thank you.
Jon.

Comment: Please provide some more details and context by showing us what you have got so far.

Comment: Added my code per your request.

Comment: Is this question related to Server Authentication, or is it Mutual Authentication (Client and Server)?

Comment: Mutual authentication.